# Bscsacn API Logs operators concatenation

Tags: bscscan

I looked at the following doc page: https://docs.bscscan.com/api-endpoints/logs

Unfortunately, I cannot combine operator in order to get the following logic:

```
topic0 and (topic1 or topic2)
```

I tried:

```
topic0: my_topic0
topic0_1_opr: and
topic0_2_opr: and 
topic1: my_topic1
topic1_2_opr: or
topic2: my_topic2
topic0: my_topic0

topic0_1_opr: and
topic1: my_topic1
topic1_2_opr: or
topic2: my_topic2

topic0: my_topic0
topic0_2_opr: and 
topic1: my_topic1
topic1_2_opr: or
topic2: my_topic2
```

There's no such way to resolve as I want. It looks like the **or** operation come always at the end, thus I got always this behaviour:

```
(topic0 and topic1) or topic2
```